# Import module with require syntax even though module uses import/export syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JavaScript class defined as:

```js
// MyClass.js
module.exports = class MyClass {
  //...
}
```

This is imported elsewhere as:

```js
// otherModule.js
const MyClass = require('./MyClass');
```

I'm trying to convert `MyClass` to TypeScript, so it's now defined as:

```
// MyClass.ts
class MyClass {
  // ...
}
export default MyClass;
```

I need to continue to import this using the `require` syntax in JavaScript files, however do so I need to do either:

```js
// otherModule.js
const MyClass = require('./MyClass').default;
// or
const { default: MyClass } = require('./MyClass');
```

Is there any way I can avoid having to explicitly specify that I'm importing `default`? Ideally I'd want to continue importing this with `const MyClass = require('./MyClass');`, if possible, even if this means I need to change how my TypeScript class is defined/exported.

Comment: Why do you still want to use `require`? Just use import and let tsc compile to cjs if you want.

Comment: I dont _want_ to, but I'm trying to refactor a common library that's used by many other repositories. The library will be refactored to TS and will use import/export, but I dont want to have to refactor all the code that imports this and change the way it imports it (that time will come, but way down the line)

Answer (score -1):

Set - esModuleInterop to true in your tsconfig
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop

```
{
   esModuleInterop: true
}
```